# why there pion/webrtc generate candidate list have no tcp address

Tags: go, webrtc, turn, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

I want use golang pion/webrtc to publish local video file to a video server, bug this video server only support TCP connection, when i generate offer SDP by pion/webrtc code and candidate list have no one TCP candidate, so ICE connect failed.
When I use chrome as a webrtc client to publish camera video, it's success, I don't how to make chrome disable TCP candidate, I checked candidcate from chrome and pion/webrtc, I found the difference is the candidate TCP address, I tried all way to let pion/webrtc generate an TCP candidate address, but all failed, please help me.

there is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "github.com/pion/webrtc/v3"
    "github.com/pion/webrtc/v3/pkg/media"
    "github.com/pion/webrtc/v3/pkg/media/h264reader"
)

func main() {

    // 创建PeerConnection配置
    config := webrtc.Configuration{
        ICEServers: []webrtc.ICEServer{
            {
                URLs: []string{"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
            },
        },
        ICETransportPolicy: webrtc.ICETransportPolicyAll,
    }

    // 创建PeerConnection
    peerConnection, err := webrtc.NewPeerConnection(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    videoTrack, err := NewH264LocalStaticSampleVideoTrack("test.h264", 25)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if rtpSender, err := peerConnection.AddTrack(videoTrack); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        go func() {
            for {

                buf := make([]byte, 1024*1024)
                var rtcpErr error
                if _, _, rtcpErr = rtpSender.Read(buf); rtcpErr != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("read error: %v", rtcpErr.Error())
                    return
                }
            }
        }()
    }

    offer, err := peerConnection.CreateOffer(nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = peerConnection.SetLocalDescription(offer)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    wait := webrtc.GatheringCompletePromise(peerConnection)
    <-wait

    fmt.Printf("Local SDP: %v", peerConnection.LocalDescription().SDP)
}

func NewH264LocalStaticSampleVideoTrack(videoFile string, fps int) (videoTrack *webrtc.TrackLocalStaticSample, err error) {
    if videoFile == "" {
        err = fmt.Errorf("videoFile is empty")
        return
    }

    var videoFileAbs string
    videoFileAbs, err = filepath.Abs(videoFile)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    _, err = os.Stat(videoFileAbs)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    videoTrack, err = webrtc.NewTrackLocalStaticSample(webrtc.RTPCodecCapability{
        MimeType: webrtc.MimeTypeH264,
    }, "video", fmt.Sprintf("rtckit/%s", uuid.New().String()))
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    go h264VideoFileConsumer(videoTrack, videoFileAbs, time.Duration(1000/fps)*time.Millisecond)

    return
}

func h264VideoFileConsumer(videoTrack *webrtc.TrackLocalStaticSample, videoFile string, videoFps time.Duration) {
    for {
        file, h264Err := os.Open(videoFile)
        if h264Err != nil {

            continue
        }

        h264, h264Err := h264reader.NewReader(file)
        if h264Err != nil {

            continue
        }

        buf := make(chan []byte, 1024*1024) // 1MB?

        var wg sync.WaitGroup

        wg.Add(2)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for data := range buf {
                sample := media.Sample{Data: data, Duration: videoFps}

                if h264Err1 := videoTrack.WriteSample(sample); h264Err1 != nil {

                    continue
                }
            }
        }()

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            ticker := time.NewTicker(videoFps)
            for ; true; <-ticker.C {
                nal, h264Err := h264.NextNAL()
                if h264Err == io.EOF {

                    break
                }
                if h264Err != nil {

                    break
                }

                buf <- nal.Data
            }

            close(buf)
        }()

        wg.Wait()
        _ = file.Close()
    }
}
```

this the offer i get:

```
offer2: v=0
o=- 3976125905671053001 1681720949 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 31:A1:C7:4B:05:14:A3:7E:FE:CA:9C:4D:91:F0:29:6C:01:BF:20:67:DF:AA:EA:06:29:A4:DD:3F:F0:AA:5B:BD
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=group:BUNDLE 0
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 121 127 120 125 107 108 109 123 118 116
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=ice-ufrag:ZjDGAGZtPHgWMfWa
a=ice-pwd:bJJRYUMfPcshoPCHTSfkyfrzwiJIiQkm
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb 
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:97 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=0
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb 
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtcp-fb:99 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:99 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:99 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:100 VP9/90000
a=fmtp:100 profile-id=1
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb 
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtcp-fb:101 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:101 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:101 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb 
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=102
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:121 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb 
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=127
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:120 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb 
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtcp-fb:107 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:107 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:107 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb 
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtcp-fb:109 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:109 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:109 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:123 H264/90000
a=fmtp:123 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640032
a=rtcp-fb:123 goog-remb 
a=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:123 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:118 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:118 apt=123
a=rtcp-fb:118 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:118 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:118 transport-cc 
a=rtpmap:116 ulpfec/90000
a=rtcp-fb:116 nack 
a=rtcp-fb:116 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:116 transport-cc 
a=extmap:1 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=ssrc:554659860 cname:rtckit/53bd9691-40c4-4a58-9165-c7579c4b5031
a=ssrc:554659860 msid:rtckit/53bd9691-40c4-4a58-9165-c7579c4b5031 video
a=ssrc:554659860 mslabel:rtckit/53bd9691-40c4-4a58-9165-c7579c4b5031
a=ssrc:554659860 label:video
a=msid:rtckit/53bd9691-40c4-4a58-9165-c7579c4b5031 video
a=sendrecv
a=candidate:4113284106 1 udp 2130706431 101.4.122.16 41267 typ host
a=candidate:4113284106 2 udp 2130706431 101.4.122.16 41267 typ host
a=candidate:3528925834 1 udp 2130706431 172.18.0.1 33655 typ host
a=candidate:3528925834 2 udp 2130706431 172.18.0.1 33655 typ host
a=candidate:233762139 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 53508 typ host
a=candidate:233762139 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 53508 typ host
a=candidate:300762037 1 udp 1694498815 178.173.224.70 56107 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 56107
a=candidate:300762037 2 udp 1694498815 178.173.224.70 56107 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 56107
a=end-of-candidates
```

Best withes~

I try to add ICE Server In localhost and use `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302`, and ask from chatGPT,  it all didn't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Pion doesn't enable ICE-TCP candidates.

You can enable them via the [SettingEngine.SetICETCPMux](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pion/webrtc/v3#SettingEngine.SetICETCPMux)

See [examples/ice-tcp](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/ice-tcp) for a full featured example of how to use this API.

Best of luck, and thanks for using Pion!

Comment: I had update my code, then I had offer with TCP candidate, but the connecting always failed, I'm sure there no firewall between client and server, because the server and client run at same machine, and server's candidate is `a=candidate:tcpcandidate 1 tcp 105 127.0.0.1 8000 typ host tcptype passive`, it's a localhost address, I try to use Chrome do the same thing, it's run correctly. Is there any thing need to do except set an TCP engine? I post my updated code to `https://github.com/AHAOAHA/pion-webrtc-demo` you can test with that. thanks!!!

Comment: it seems like `tcptype passive` is not my want, i need a `tcptype active` to create the ice connect.

Comment: Pion now has active TCP candidates. Thanks for bringing this up @ahaooahaz